# PHP: Почему данные из одного массива не перезаписываются в заданном формате в другой, пустой?

Tags: php, массивы, строки, циклы, while

Хочу совместить в одном цикле while и получение массива из csv ($assoc_array), и его оформление для отправки в таблицу базы ($temp_array). $temp_array не хочет принимать данные от $assoc_array. Консоль выдает то, что показано на картинке после кода (смотри ниже). Почему так происходит? Что я делаю не так? Когда $temp_array был в отдельном цикле foreach, все работало именно в таком виде.. А сейчас, когда решил объединить две операции в один цикл (оптимизации ради) не срабатывает.. Не могу понять почему. Может быть, кто-нибудь уделит время и подскажет причину? Буду благодарен за любой совет..

```
if (($handle = fopen( '017.csv', 'r' )) !== false) {

// Получаю из csv ассоциированный массив PHP, готовый к загрузке в базу данных.
    fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {

        $assoc_array[] = array(
            "year"          => 2020,
            "is_sender"     => empty(trim($data[6])) ? 0 : 1,
            "is_receiver"   => empty(trim($data[7])) ? 0 : 1,
            "is_holder"     => empty(trim($data[8])) ? 0 : 1,
            "is_declarant"  => empty(trim($data[9])) ? 0 : 1,
            "sender"        => trim($data[6]),
            "receiver"      => trim($data[7]),
            "holder"        => trim($data[8]),
            "declarant"     => trim($data[9]),
            "_sys_number"   => trim($data[0]),
            "_key"          => trim($data[5]),
            "_status"       => 0,
            "inn"           => trim($data[1]));

        var_dump($assoc_array);

        $temp_array[] = "($assoc_array[year], '$assoc_array[is_sender]', '$assoc_array[is_receiver]', '$assoc_array[is_holder]', '$assoc_array[is_declarant]','$assoc_array[sender]', '$assoc_array[receiver]', '$assoc_array[holder]', '$assoc_array[declarant]', '$assoc_array[_sys_number]', '$assoc_array[_key]', '$assoc_array[_status]', '$assoc_array[inn]')";

        /*       $clue = count(array_keys($data));

               if( $counter%100 == 0 || $clue = $counter) {
                   $query =
                       "INSERT INTO database.table
                       (year,is_sender,is_receiver,is_holder,is_declarant,sender,receiver,holder,declarant,_sys_number,_key,_status,inn)
                   VALUES " . implode(",", $temp_array);

                   if ( !$b->Query( $query ) )
                   {
                       print("ERROR CONNECT SQL");
                       exit;
                   }

                   $temp_array = array();

               }

               $counter++; */
        exit;
    }

    fclose($handle);

}

?>
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Comment: А всего-то и надо что сделать - `print_r($assoc_array)` и увидеть его структуру.

Comment: Я смотрел, что выдает массив. Приложил результат print_r к заданию (последняя картинка). Но по прежнему не понимаю, в чем ошибка..

Comment: В том что там есть ключ `0`?

Comment: Когда $temp_array был в отдельном цикле - foreach, все было в порядке и он наполнялся в этом виде..

Comment: Ключ увидел, но почему он в foreach непотребовался? Извините, что, может, что-то не догоняю..

Comment: Не догоняешь да, как работает `foreach`.

Comment: да, вы правы, понял ошибку..